# Colby grew up "on" a cattle ranch in Texas

Tags: prepositions, in-on-at

looking at English magazine, I found a example.
Colby grew up "on" a cattle ranch in Texas.
why not "in"?  ranch is a place, isn't it?

Comment: In English, the tendency is to use the preposition "on" for things that are perceived as flat.

Answer (score 0):

There are many differences between British and American English for which preposition is various situations.

These Google books analyses, [Br](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20a%20ranch%2Fon%20a%20ranch&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28in%20a%20ranch%20/%20on%20a%20ranch%29%3B%2Cc0) and [Am](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20a%20ranch%2Fon%20a%20ranch&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28in%20a%20ranch%20/%20on%20a%20ranch%29%3B%2Cc0), suggest 'on a ranch' is preferred by over 90% for both.